# Angular Material | Material Button behaves differently when button text is pressed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Consider the following code:

HTML:

```
<button mat-flat-button id="test" (click)="toggle($event)">Click me!</button>
```

Component:

```
toggle(event) {
  let id: string = (event.target as Element).id;
  console.log(id)
  console.log(event.target)
}
```

Pressing the button will fire the `toggle` function with event as parameter. 
System will log `"test"` (id) and a button event.

Pressing the *text on the button* will log a undefined id and a `span` with class `mat-button-wrapper`

**Question:** If button text is pressed I want to get the button event target (and not the span event target), how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click event is behaving correctly. In JavaScript, when an event is fired on a source element, it "bubbles up" from the source and propagates up through the tree of ancestor elements.

So when you have a DOM structure like this:

```
<button mat-flat-button>
    <span>Click me!</span>
</button>
```

A click event on the `span` will propagate up to the `button` as it bubbles up to the document root.

If you want to get a hold of the button element, you can use a [Template Reference Variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-) and pass that into your event handler:

```
<button mat-flat-button id="test" #testButton (click)="toggle(testButton)">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the button element into the event handler directly by assigning a template reference variable to the button:

```
<button mat-flat-button id="test" #button (toggle)="toggle(button._elementRef.nativeElement)">Click me!</button>

toggle(button) {
  console.log(button.id);
}
```

You can also use the event target and when it isn't the button look at its parent (or parent's parent depending on what you put inside the button):

```
toggle(event) {
  if (event.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
  } else {
    console.log(event.target.parentElement.id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Should just be `toggle(button)`?

Comment: You can do it that way too - but that's not the HTMLButtonElement - it's an angular thing - button._elementRef.nativeElement.